# Can somebody help me to implement extension Subject Alternative Names using BouncyCastle?

Tags: java, certificate, x509certificate, bouncycastle, subject-alternative-name

I have some string, that is separated with comma. I have to add all extension that match any of GeneralName for Subject Alternative Names extension. Can somebody finish for loop for me?

```
    @Override
public boolean saveKeypair(String arg0) {

    KeyPair keyPair = generateKeyPair(Integer.parseInt(access.getPublicKeyParameter()));

    PrivateKey privateKey = keyPair.getPrivate();
    PublicKey publicKey = keyPair.getPublic();

    X500Name name = new X500Name(access.getSubject());
    BigInteger serial = new BigInteger(access.getSerialNumber());
    Date notBefore = access.getNotBefore();
    Date notAfter = access.getNotAfter();
    X509v3CertificateBuilder certBuilder = new JcaX509v3CertificateBuilder(name, serial, notBefore, notAfter, name,
            publicKey);

    // BEGIN extensions
    // certificate policies
    boolean isCritPol = access.isCritical(3);
    PolicyInformation[] policies = new PolicyInformation[1];
    policies[0] = new PolicyInformation(new ASN1ObjectIdentifier("2.16.840.1.101.2.1.11.5"),
            new DERSequence(new PolicyQualifierInfo(access.getCpsUri())));
    try {
        certBuilder.addExtension(Extension.certificatePolicies, isCritPol, new CertificatePolicies(policies));
    } catch (CertIOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    // END CP

    // subject alternative name
    List<GeneralName> altNames = new ArrayList<GeneralName>();
    String [] altSubNames = access.getAlternativeName(5);

    for(String altName : altSubNames){
        // I NEED THIS LOOP, AND I DON'T KNOW HOW TO DO IT
    }

    // END SAN

    // END extensions


    try {
        // Content Signer
        Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
        ContentSigner sigGen = new JcaContentSignerBuilder(signatureAlgorithm).setProvider(providerName)
                .build(privateKey);

        // Certificate
        X509Certificate certificate = new JcaX509CertificateConverter().setProvider(providerName)
                .getCertificate(certBuilder.build(sigGen));

     certificate.verify(publicKey);

        X509Certificate[] chain = new X509Certificate[1];       
        chain[0] = certificate;
        keyStore.setKeyEntry(arg0, privateKey, password.toCharArray(), chain);

    } catch (OperatorCreationException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (CertificateException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchProviderException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SignatureException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (KeyStoreException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return true;
}

// BEGIN of functions for saveKeypair

public KeyPair generateKeyPair(int keySize) {
    KeyPair keyPair = null;

    try {
        KeyPairGenerator keyGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance(algorithm);
        keyGenerator.initialize(keySize);
        keyPair = keyGenerator.generateKeyPair();
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return keyPair;
}



// END of functions for saveKeypair
```

The rest of the function is working.

I am using BouncyCastle in Java. `altSubName` is an array, of some Strings. And those Strings should be somehow checked which of SubjectAlternativeName they are, and the Extension containing all that general names should be added.

Comment: *Can somebody finish for loop for me??* We are not a remote programming facility for you, finish it yourself. Stop using StackOverflow as a shortcut for your laziness.

Comment: I am not lazy, i have tried some ways that are not correct. I could just posted my incorrect function, and than this would be ok question? I really need help with this one. Because everything I found on Internet is about adding only one Alternative Name.

Comment: I have one idea, and that is to use regex and check what is the type of Alternative Name, I am interested if there is some better solution?

Comment: A GeneralName can be of lots of different types (dnsName, ipAddress, rfc822name and so on), do you know what exactly your strings should be? You said "Strings should be somehow checked which of SubjectAlternativeName they are" - do you have some examples of the strings and how it's decided their types?

Comment: And what version of BouncyCastle are you using?

Comment: It can be any string. I must recognize if string is dnsName, ipAddress, rfc822name and so on, and to add it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [RFC 5280](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280#section-4.2.1.6), some fields of the **Subject Alternative Name** extension have a defined format:

- rfc822Name: format is defined in [RFC 2821](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2821#section-4.1.2)
- ipAddress: defined in [RFC 791](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc791)
- dnsName: [RFC 1034](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1034#section-3.5)

And so on (take a look at the RFC 5280 link, it's very detailed).

So, to know what's the field corresponding to each `String`, you must check if they have the format defined in each of the fields.

For `rfc822Name` I've found this monster regex:

```
String rfc822Regex = "(?:[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*|\"(?:[\\x01-\\x08\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x1f\\x21\\x23-\\x5b\\x5d-\\x7f]|\\\\[\\x01-\\x09\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x7f])*\")@(?:(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?|\\[(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?|[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]:(?:[\\x01-\\x08\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x1f\\x21-\\x5a\\x53-\\x7f]|\\\\[\\x01-\\x09\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x7f])+)\\])";
String s = "test_ad.fade@mail.com";
if (s.matches(rfc822Regex)) {
    // is valid email
}
```

For the other fields, you can search regexes for each specific format. I think the only problem is the `otherName` field, because it can have **any** format (it must be specified for each Certificate Authority):

```
OtherName ::= SEQUENCE {
    type-id    OBJECT IDENTIFIER,
    value      [0] EXPLICIT ANY DEFINED BY type-id }
```

Anyway, a generic code will be like this (assuming you already searched how to validate each of the specific formats):

```
// check the format and add with the correct field type
if (isValidEmail(altName)) {
    altNames.add(new GeneralName(GeneralName.rfc822Name, "user@mail.com"));
} else if (isValidDnsName(altName)) {
    altNames.add(new GeneralName(GeneralName.dNSName, "test.com"));
} else if (isValidIpAddress(altName)) {
    altNames.add(new GeneralName(GeneralName.iPAddress, "127.0.0.1"));
}
// ... and so on, for all GeneralName types
```

Then you add the extension to `certBuilder`:

```
GeneralNames subjectAltNames = GeneralNames.getInstance(new DERSequence((GeneralName[]) altNames.toArray(new GeneralName[] {})));
certBuilder.addExtension(Extension.subjectAlternativeName, false, subjectAltNames);
```

Comment: Thank you very much! do you know some more regular expression for some other of GeneralNames?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know, but it shouldn't be hard to find (they're all very known standards, maybe even BouncyCastle has it, but I'm not sure)